# C# Handle a dialog's button click in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dialog, click

I have a form. In that I got to show a dialog (on some circumstances) with Text and a Cancel button. I want to catch the event of that button in my form Or know if that cancel button was clicked.

How can this be done ? I believe this should be possible but can't make out how ?

From my mainForm I have BackgroundWorker. When the backgroundWorker is started I open a childForm (with a Label and a button) and when the background task is over, I close the childForm. What I want more is : when the button of childForm is clicked the ongoing task of backgroundWorker should be cancelled. 
**SOLUTION**

In my childForm I have set CancelButton property as cancelBtn for the form. The othe code is :

```
    private bool cancel;
    public bool Cancel
    {
        get { return cancel; }
        set { cancel = value; }
    }
    // Set the flag as true to indicate that Cancel button was actually pressed
    private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel = true;
    }
```

In mainForm :

```
    childDlg = new ChildDialog();

    // wHILE cALLING
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            msg = "Connecting...";
            childDlg .set(msg, "");
            if (!childDlg .IsAccessible)
            {
                // This is caught even when the dialog is closed   
                if (childDlg .ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) {
                     if (childDlg.Cancel == true) { // Was really cancelBtn pressed  
                         // NOW ONLY do my stuff 
                     }   
                }
            }
```

I had tried using @DeveloperX technique i.e. EventHandler in parent class, but the parent class method was nver being called. Tried a lot but couldn't success. Then tried of @RobinJ's technique and it worked. I just had to add flag to identify was really cancel button pressed or jjst windw was closed normally.

Thanks to all of you for tryig to help me out. I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Actually not necessary that the user got to click "Cance" button. The dialog appears till the main form performs an activity. If the activity is finished, the dialog should be closed by main. If user clicks cancel then other code has to be performed by the main form. This is the exact scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the form that should catch the event:

```
frmDialog.ShowDialog();
```

And this in the btnCancel_Click event of the dialog:

```
return DialogResult.Cancel();
```

Sorry if I'm confusing VB and C# here, but it's pretty much the same.

Comment: no bn click event returns void so can't return as Dialog.Cancel();

Comment: ..?<br>`if (frmDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) {}` should work... Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thanks RobinJ, it did work. But even if window was closed normally it would fire as Dialog.Cancel. To handle this I added a boolean flag and tested the value to know if Cancel button was pressed or just on closing this event is caught. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Set `DialogResult` property to either `DialogResult.Ok` or `DialogResult.Cancel`

Then in the parent form:

```
Form form = new Form();
DialogResult results = form.DialogResult;

if(results == DialogResult.Ok)
{

... make magic

}
else
{
...
}
```

Comment: I want the form to be visible until my background task is over. With ths style, when I press a buton in form then only it will proceed ahead. This is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can create an event for the form that shows the dialog
and handle this event in parent form
in case the user clicks on ok fire event with specefic parameter and for cancel another parameter (such dialogresult.cancel)

an pseudo implementation can be like this

```
public class FormChild : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public event EventHandler DialogCanceled;
    public event EventHandler DialogConfirmed;
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        using (var dialogForm = new   FormDialog())
        {
            if (dialogForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (DialogConfirmed != null)
                    DialogConfirmed(this,new EventArgs());
            }
            else
            {
                if (DialogCanceled != null)
                    DialogCanceled(this,new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ParentForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public void callChild()
    {
        using (var f = new FormChild())
        {
            f.DialogCanceled += new EventHandler(f_DialogCanceled);
            f.DialogConfirmed += new EventHandler(f_DialogConfirmed);
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    void f_DialogConfirmed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void f_DialogCanceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeveloperX, f_DialogCanceled is not being caught. I have added my code in question.

Comment: put a Breakpoint on Console.WriteLine("HEY CANCEL BUTTON IS CAUGHT HER ....") and check what happens after click

Comment: Also check you didnt put childDlg.DialogCanceled += new EventHandler(childDlg_DialogCanceled); after showing dialog form

Comment: iT NEVER REACHES THE childDlg_DialogCanceled(object sender, EventArgs e) method. I added the childDlg.DialogCanceled += new EventHandler(childDlg_DialogCanceled); again after showDialog(), but yet it doesn't reach there only.

Comment: i meant you should not put after showDialog! Can i have your source completely atleat this this parts of code

Comment: @DeveloperX, the code of calling the childDlg is also added. Whole code related is updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `ShowDialog` method on the form you need to show as a dialog and then use the `DialogResult` property to communicate to the parent form the result of the dialog operation.

This way you handle the button click on the form that owns the button but set the `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.Cancel` to specify that the user pressed the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Form form = new Form();
switch (form.ShowDialog())
{
    case DialogResult.Ok:
    {
        ....
        Break;
    }
    case DialogResult.Cancel:
    {
        ....
        Break;
    }
}
```

Set the `Form.AcceptButton` and `Form.CancelButton` properties to the appropriate buttons.

---

Refer to the following:

[Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

[DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[Form.AcceptButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx)

[Form.CancelButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A dialog is usually a blocking event, where eventhandling by the parent form would make no sense at all.

If it isn't a modal dialog, you can always create one or several public events in the popup form, that are triggered when the buttons are clicked. These events can then be caught by the parent form.

Don't expose your buttons to the parent form, it would be terrible oo-programming.